# Usei position em uma section e toda div que adiciono na outra section se posiciona na anterior

Tags: css, html5, posicionamento

Utilizei o `position` `absolute` para posicionar duas `divs` da forma que eu queria dentro de uma `section` e agora na proxima `section` que quero incluir, todos os elementos são automaticamente posicionados no local da `section` anterior. Queria saber como faço para a proxima `section` não ficar sobrepondo a anterior.Assim está o meu css:

```
.description{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}

.textinside{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 50px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

#photoback{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.photo1{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 600px;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Nesse exemplo, coloca um `position: relative`; Na div pai, assim você consegue controlar as divs filhos, com `position: absolute;`

```css
.pai {
  border: 1px solid red;
  postion: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.filho {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    postion:absolute;
    max-width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filho">Elment</div>
  <div class="filho">Elment</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).